# Vector inequality for a scalar difference of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces

A student posed an interesting problem to me the other day and embarrassingly I could not prove or disprove it even though it appears relatively simple.

The question was:

Given vectors $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|\mathbf{v}\|$,$\|\mathbf{w}\|\leq R$ and distinct scalars $a, b > 0$ does there exist a constant $C=C(R)$ (depending only on $R$, not on $a$ or $b$) such that

$$\|a\mathbf{v}-b\mathbf{w}\|\leq C |a-b|\\$$

The proof for the one-dimensional case was simple but in higher dimensions it doesn't seem as obvious to prove.

Any help in proving/disproving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, we could have $a=b \neq 0$, while the vectors are not equal, so the inequality cannot hold in general for finite $C$.

Comment: Good point, I mucked up the phrasing. Edited to exclude the trivial case where it fails.

Comment: Unfortunately that issue remains pertinent.  Will illustrate below:

Answer (score 1):

Let **v = -w**, and $\|\mathbf{v}\|=\|\mathbf{w}\|= R$. Then we need
$$C \ge \frac{a+b}{|a-b|}R$$

The RHS now cannot be bound from above by any finite number which does not depend on $b/a$.